# Multiple entries within the hour should be counted only once

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
//Query data
public void GetDataByCountry(string gameID)
{
    string query = "SELECT clickDate, userIp FROM gameLinks 
                     where userCountry = @userCountry";

    using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userCountry", gameID);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        dgvHourIp.Rows.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] row = new[]
            {
                reader[0].ToString(), //hour
                reader[1].ToString()  //ip
            };
            dgvHourIp.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Output:**  [image]

**Desired Output** [image]

How can i manipulate this result to be filtered by this condition:
- **if the same IP has multiple entries within the hour, it should be counted only once**

Should i try to convert the `reader[]` in C# and then try to compare it?
Or should i use only SQL queryes instead?

Comment: I think i have an understanding of what youre asking for but can you clarify by what you want the expected results to be

Comment: also, the easiest ways to do this are in the SQL Query, or by using LINQ when you have the data back as an enumerable object

Comment: My 2 cents: you should act on what you do first: the execution of a SQL query to retrieve the results you expect, because I think you don't need to manipulate your program for something that you should expect on first basis (a query that groups the result by IP address). Of course, it's just my opinion. It's a matter of what you want to modify and not what is best.

Comment: which is the desired date (hour)?

Comment: I added the desired output in the question.

Comment: actually first two items with 5.5.5.5 ip should be counted once too. because if you see they have less than one hour delta .

Comment: what dbms are you using? would you like to suppress it by code or by sql query?

Comment: ive removed my answer for the moment, what youre after is best done in LINQ, when i have a bit more time i'll code it up for you

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary hahaha you're right! But you get my point without looking at the minutes too much xD

Comment: If your intention is to return one record per IP address per hour of the day, do it in the SQL. I'd select distinct with IP address, datapart(hour, time field), convert(date, timefield) as a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Cris suggestion, records should be ordered by ip, date.

```
string query = "SELECT clickDate, userIp FROM gameLinks where userCountry = @userCountry order by userIp, clickDate";
```

The use two variables just to store last row.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

srtring lastIp = "";
DateTime lastDate;

dgvHourIp.Rows.Clear();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string[] row = new[]
    {
        reader[0].ToString(), //hour
        reader[1].ToString()  //ip
     };

     if (lastIp != "")
     {
         TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]).Substract(lastDate));
         if (lastIp == row[1] && ts.TotalMinutes < 60)
         {
             lastIp = row[1];
             continue;
         }
     }
     lastIp = row[1];
     lastDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]);

     dgvHourIp.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Only one thing, what happens when:

```
record 1 --> 40 min --> record 2 --> 50 min --> record 3
```

Comment: It looks like some structure (perhaps a Dictionary) is needed to do that on a per-IP address basis. Maybe with removing older entries to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: Hey this seems to work! It's just for Demo purposes, so i don't worry about memory that much right now. But other people reading this should be aware.

Comment: @Cris You might need to change the query to use `order by userIP, clickDate` as otherwise two-or-more alternating IP addresses won't be caught.

Comment: and I removed `lastDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]);` inside the if statement just to get all the records in one hour delta

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
DataTable dttemp = yourtableName.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Hour", "IPAddress");
```

now,you have a distinct data inside **dttemp** variable

or
you can use LINQ

```
var distrows= yourtableName.AsEnumerable().Distinct();
```